# Am I using pointers to pointers right?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am a newbie in C++ programming and trying to learn the language from reading an Ebook called  [Jumping into C++ by Alex Allain](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++book/), and I have currently finished the dynamic memory allocation chapter and I must say that I find pointers difficult to understand.

At the end of the chapter is a series of practice problem I can try out, I have completed the first problem (took me a while to get my code working) which is to **write a function that builds the multiplication table of arbitrary dimensions** (you have to use pointers for the problem), but I am not satisfied with my solution if it's correct and if I am using the pointers the right way, I want someone who has experience to point out the flaws, if there are, below is my own solution to the problem:

```
// pointerName.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void multTable(int size){

    int ** x, result;
    x = new int*[size]; //  lets declare a pointer that will point to another pointer :).
    result = 0; 

    for(int h = 0; h < size; h++){ // lets store the address of an array of integers.
            x[h] = new int [size];      
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "*********************************" << std::endl; // lets seperate. 
    for(int i=0; i < size+1; i++){ // lets use the pointer like a two-dimensional array.
        for(int j=0; j < size+1; j++){
            result = i*j; // lets multiply the variables initialized from the for loop.
            **x = result; // lets inialize the table.
            std::cout << **x << "\t"; // dereference it and print out the whole table.
        }
        std::cout  << std::endl;
    }
    /************* DEALLOCATE THE MEMORY SPACE ************/
    for(int index = 0; index < size; index++){
        delete [] x[index]; // free each row first.  
    }
    delete [] x; // free the pointer itself.
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int num;
    std::cout << "Please Enter a valid number: ";
    std::cin >> num; // Lets prompt the user for a number.
    multTable(num);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This kind of question belongs best on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: just be careful of two for loops : `for(int i=0; i < size+1; i++)`

Comment: thanks for the comments, @billz why is that?.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i < size+1; i++){ x[j] }` // out of boundry?

Comment: @billz ok, I put add 1 there cause it does not print out the last product of the multiplication table, are there alternative ways to it.

Comment: It's [recommended practice](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#whitespace) not to write something like: `int ** x, result;` because `x` and `result` get declared with different types, which is just confusing. Instead declare them separately: `int** x; int result;` (They should be on separate lines, but comments can't contain newlines)

`

Comment: @Carl Norum: This only belongs on codereview if there are no bugs. Unfortunately there are bugs and the reviewers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com would have booted it back here as they only review working code. stackoverflow is for fixing broken code like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What billz said and also **x must change to x[i][j]. Since you seem new it would be good practice to print the multiplication table as a seperate block (outside the two for loops).

Comment: do you mean print it out something like `std::cout << **(x + 3 * size + 2); `? in my own understanding of that syntax above I'm trying to access `x[3][2]`, is that right?

Comment: thanks for taking your time answering my question, I did change the `**x` to `x[i][j]` but this time it only print out `0` which I guess the first element.

Comment: Try it out by printing the address next to the value (`cout << &x[3][2] << "::" << x[3][2]`). It is basically what you mentioned but not using the same syntax. x[3] stands for the whole row and is equal to (x+3) and the second element will be *((int *)*((int **)x + 3) + 2). The braces are important since the addition causes the *size multiplication for 3 implicitly based on the type of x. Don't be boggled by the strange notation, it is to help you understand. Start from the innermost braces and you'll get it. You can simply write it as *(*(x + 3) + 2) and the compiler will understand it fine.

Comment: You need to change both locations to x[i][j]:
`x[i][j] = result; // lets inialize the table.
std::cout << x[i][j] << "\t"; // dereference it and print out the whole table.`

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
for(int i=0; i < size+1; i++){ // lets use the pointer like a two-dimensional array.
    for(int j=0; j < size+1; j++)
```

The loops are going to far, if you had done the next bot correctly would have caused a problem because you index beyond the end of the array. Fortunately for you (there is a following bug). These lines should have been:

```
for(int i=0; i < size; i++){ // lets use the pointer like a two-dimensional array.
    for(int j=0; j < size; j++)
```

This line:

```
 **x = result; // lets inialize the table.
```

You probably mean:

```
x[i][j] = result; // lets inialize the table.
```

Note:
    // Note because of your first bug
    x[i] would have gone off the end of the array by one.

When you allocate an array:

```
 x = new int[size];
```

You can access the elements:
     x[0] => x[size-1]

This is because there are `size` elements but you are starting your count at `0`.

Comment: thanks man, I add `size+1;` because it does not print out the last column of the table, but the first answer says that it's best practice to print out the table outside the two for loop which I have not done and I am currently trying that out right now.